# Does GCP DataFlow provide any Class for interacting with Google Retail API [Like For BQ it is BigQueryIO]

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Does GCP DataFlow provide any Class for interacting with Google Retail API [Like For BQ it is BigQueryIO from apache beam]

Need gcp retail class information for invoking retail api in dataflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific class for using Google Retail API. You can call the retail API from your own code in your `DoFn` in your pipeline. You will have to be careful about using too much quota from the retail API.